# Bash autocompletion for an alias

Tags: bash, autocomplete, bashrc

This is in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias p='sudo apt-get'; complete -F _apt_get p
```

I've found the autocompletion only works if I've used autocompletion for `apt-get` at least once before trying to use it with the `p` alias.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because completions are loaded dynamically by the "bash-completions" library. This works because the completion specifications are kept "in a file corresponding to the name of the command" (man bash).

Add this to your .bashrc:

```
_completion_loader apt-get
```